# jQuery selector help

Tags: jquery

I have a large HTML document which has roughly this structure:

```
<div id="a">
    <!-- more html code here -->
    <span id="title">...</span>
    <!-- more html code here -->
</div>
<div id="b">
    <!-- more html code here -->
    <span id="title">...</span>
    <!-- more html code here -->
</div>
...
...
<div id="z">
    <!-- more html code here -->
    <span id="title">...</span>
    <!-- more html code here -->
</div>
```

Notice that the outer DIVs have IDs which are unique ("a", "b", ..., "z"), but inner SPANs have IDs which is non-unique ("title").

To select a SPAN which is inside the DIV "q", for instance, I tried using this:

```
$("#q").find("#title");
```

This runs fast on FF and Chrome but the find() method takes a long time to execute in IE8 (and IE7). Is there some other way I can do this?

Please let me know if I can provide any further information.

Comment: *" but inner SPANs have IDs which is non-unique"* This is not valid, IDs must be unique. You should use classes instead. `<span class="title">...</span>`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should change your markup to use classes for the `<span>` elements instead of IDs since IDs must be unique.

```
<div id="a">
    <!-- more html code here -->
    <span class="title">...</span>
    <!-- more html code here -->
</div>
<div id="b">
    <!-- more html code here -->
    <span class="title">...</span>
    <!-- more html code here -->
</div>
...
...
<div id="z">
    <!-- more html code here -->
    <span class="title">...</span>
    <!-- more html code here -->
</div>
```

then:

```
$("#q").find(".title");
```

If I remember correctly, IE in particular has trouble with non-unique IDs. Changing your code to above may do the trick for you.

Comment: You are right. Wish it was that way. But I have little control over those IDs. Anyways, thanks for your answer... looks like I am hosed here.

Comment: If you only have one span you can do it via $("#q").find("span")

Comment: There can be more than one spans. But based on what you suggest, I can try $("#q").find("span#title"). Maybe that would help a little.

Comment: @Rohit - If Marko's suggestion doesn't work because each `div` has more than one `span`, there may be another selector that will work. As long as there's some sort of predictability in each `div`, there's likely some selector that doesn't use IDs that will work.

Comment: I am going to accept this answer. I tried the other methods below, but the problem is that the document is too large with many Spans within each Div. And because of the non-unique IDs, the browser does a search through all the spans to find the one we need. Its that search that takes too much time. There is actually no performance problem on smaller documents.

Answer (score 2):

As everyone else said, the code is invalid. However, if you are stuck with it, you should be able to do this to select it correctly. Without running tests, I am not sure how performant this will be over the other method you tried:

```
$("#b span[id=title]");
```

Comment: +1 - I just left a comment (deleted) under mine suggesting the same thing, then scrolled down and saw you beat me to it by a long shot! :o)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
$("#q").find("span").each(function() {
    if($(this).attr("id") == "title") {
        $(this).css('color','red');
    }
});
```

This works for me in IE/FF